# Common pattern when using arrays in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am experienced with C++, but I only began to learn C++/CLI.
I notice the following pattern a lot:

```
array<String^>^ x;
```

How do you guys think about this? The way I interpret this is,
this is array of strings and we want them all to be on the managed heap
and that is why we use String^, but we also want the vector to be on the managed
heap and that is why we have

```
array<something>^.
```

Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++cli `ref class` must live on the managed heap.  Actual non-managed heap instances are blocked.

Both `String` and `array` are `ref class` types, so they must live on the managed heap.

C++, in order to remind the user that these are garbage-collected pointer types, and not literals or traditional pointer types, requires that you end the types with a `^`.

While this is redundant (all instances of `array<>` are `array<>^` -- hence in C# where there is no such `^` token), the reminder that this is a managed type and not a normal type probably helps when you mix managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: In C++/CLI you can also create a managed object on the stack! For example instaed of doing `Foo ^foo = gcnew Foo()` you can just write `Foo foo`, which will create the managed object (ref class) on the stack! It will also now automatically invoke the Dispose-Pattern if implemented by the class!

Comment: @jochenkalmbach I did not know that: are pointers auto-nulled or something?  Can you toss me a link at some docs that explain it?

Comment: Only `ref class` fields get automatically initialized with the default values (0 or nullptr)!

Comment: @jochenkalmbach no, I mean when the stack instance goes out of scope, what happens to pointers at it?

Comment: It is not actually on the stack.... But dispose gets called when the variable goes out of scope. Is a much nicer version of a c# using block, that also works for member variables.

Comment: The object will still be kept alive by the garbage collector as long as other handles make it reachable, but as an already disposed object, it isn't good for much.